# LinkedIn Signin for ios OAuth2, API V2. How to open the installed LinkedIn app

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Until now we have implemented an OAuth Workflow with mobile app and web-based login for LinkedIn with the help of (https://github.com/tonyli508/LinkedinSwift). Due to LinkeIn API change to V2 on 1.3.2019 we updated our app to use browser-based OAuth 2.0 workflow for LinkedIn using REST-Interface API V2, an embedded UIWebView and intercepting the request to get the token, because LinkedinSwift uses the mobile ios SDK of LinkedIn and does not support API V2.

The LinkeIn website for the SDK (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk) says "The Mobile SDK is not currently supported". Following the Link, only the REST API is documented.

Question:
Did anybody manage to use a installed LinkedIn app for authorization and using API V2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linkedin App does not provide any Deeplinks, and they want developers to use the SDK, but the LinkedIn API has been largely closed off and is only available to approved LinkedIn developers. You can request authorization here - https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program